# ¿Es prudente que el usuario pueda generar más tablas en la base de datos?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Es un poco extraña esta pregunta, pero haré lo posible por formularla de la mejor manera.

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto personal donde el usuario pueda acceder a una página web, registrar su tienda y poder tener un punto de venta en linea, para ello diseñe una base de datos donde me he encontrado con el problema de que después de un tiempo las tablas (por ejemplo, si tomamos la tabla de productos) van a ser demasiado grandes, teniendo problemas para encontrar un registro necesario entre todos los registros, pues todos los productos de todas las tiendas se guardan en una sola tabla.

Así que pensando un poco llegue a una conclusión que no había visto con ningún profesor ni en ningún libro, que se creen tablas para cada tienda, haciendo que las búsquedas siempre se lleven a cabo en una tabla, sin embargo mi duda es si este sería un buen diseño y si no estaré creando más problemas a futuro.

Ejemplo del primer diseño:
Se tiene una tabla de usuarios, tiendas, donde se guardara la información de todas las tiendas en las tablas productos, proveedores, ventas, etc. Las cuales tendras el id de la tienda a la que pertenecen.

Segundo diseño:
Se tiene la tabla usuarios y tiendas, al registrar una tienda nueva se crean las tablas anteponiendo el id de la tienda, por ejemplo, si se crea la tienda con el id "456" se crearan las tablas 456_productos, 456_proveedores, 456_ventas.

Comment: Hola @ErickSantiago. Las bases de datos están hechas para trabajar con gran cantidad de registros. No veo muy claro eso que comentas. Antes de eso, dedicaría algo de tiempo a la optimización de tablas. Por ejemplo, creando índices correctamente podrás hacer mucho más optimas tus consultas. Por otro lado, si diseñas un buen modelo de datos no deberías de tener problemas para encontrar el registro que necesites. Un saludo.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien la pregunta.... ¿Cuántos registros contienen las "tablas demasiado grandes"? Y ¿qué problema existiría para "encontrar un registro"? MySQL debería ser capaz de soportar cualquier "proyecto personal"

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría crear tablas*tiendas, ya que tener todas las tiendas en una sola tabla tomando en cuenta la cantidad de datos que vas a almacenar es demasiada, Si distribuyes una tabla para cada tienda lo tendrías todo de manera organizada. Saludos

Comment: ¿Qué información es "demasiada"? ¿No sabemos el volumen de datos, pero sabemos que es más que lo que MySQL puede manejar (que es muchísimo)?